# Measuring latent traits: Searching for a suitable model

Tags: bayesian, psychometrics, latent-variable

There is a kind of a problem related to psychometrics I keep coming across in my research again and again. Unfortunately, I failed to find appropriate statistical model to solve it. Can anybody suggest a solution?

Here is a my “supermarket” metaphor:

> You work in a supermarket which offers a diverse range of goods. Let’s
>   say hundreds or thousands of items. One day you find yourself
>   interested in a psychology and you ask a question: is it possible to
>   draw conclusions about personality of any customer given just an
>   information about what he or she puts into their shopping cart?
>
> Let’s say that personality can be described with a few numbers (e.g.
>   how extraverted he or she is, how emotionally stable...).
>
> You start looking in shopping cards of people at the checkout. At
>   first you build a training set. You check only people from you
>   neighbourhood you know personally (let’s say you know exactly the
>   values of their personality traits).
>
> Then an unknown person arrives at the cash desk. How can you estimate
>   the values of his or her personality traits?

Isssues I find problematic:

- The items give you quite a weak evidence (e.g. buying birthday
  confetti suggests higher level of extraversion but who knows the real
  motivation).
- You are assessing more than one trait at once.
- Buying a particular item means something. However, NOT buying it
  means almost nothing (the customer could have failed to find it or cannot
  afford it...). The data matrix is more like ones and NAs than ones and
  zeros.
- Items vary in their popularity. Lots of them were bought barely by
  anybody in your training set.

Comment: Have you tried ridge logistics regression and/or naive bayesian classifier. What was the accuracy achieved?

Comment: This sounds like a fundamental problem of personality research. Personality is not a great predictor of behavior, because there are so many situational factors. In addition, the supermarket sells lots of things so that any indicator will have low information - most people don't buy $some_product. You'd like to find an item type where extraverts buy version X (granny smith apples), and introverts buy version Y (golden delicious apples). But that's really hard to do.